# Why setting property in javascript object is not working?

Tags: javascript, class, object

```
 class GotoMeeting {
  constructor() {
    //get the dom element
    let self = this;
    this.audioBtn = null;
    this.email = null;
    this.name = null;
    self.clicked = false;
  }
  getElement() {
    let target = document.body;
    let MutationObserver =
      window.MutationObserver ||
      window.WebKitMutationObserver ||
      window.MozMutationObserver;
    let mutation = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.type);
      });
      this.audioBtn = document.getElementById("select-audio-none");
      let emailBtn = document.getElementById("join-email");
      let nameBtn = document.getElementById("join-name");
      let submitBtn = document.getElementById("join-submit");
      if (this.audioBtn) {
        this.audioBtn.click();
      }

      if (emailBtn && nameBtn) {
            if (this.email !== null && this.name !== null) {
                emailBtn.value = this.email;
                nameBtn.value = this.name;
                if (self.clicked === false && emailBtn.value && nameBtn.value) {
                  submitBtn.click();
                  self.clicked === true;
                  console.log("it worked :)")
                }
              }else{
                  setTimeout(()=>{checkDetail()},1000);
              }
        this.triggerMouseEvent(nameBtn, "keydown");
      }
    });
    let config = {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    };
    mutation.observe(target, config);
  }
  triggerMouseEvent(node, eventType) {
    let keyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent(eventType);
    node.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
  }
}
 let gotomeeting = new GotoMeeting();
  gotomeeting.getElement();
```

The reason why iam calling `getElement()` method is because it has to load has soon as page loads because it has mutation observer.

i am fetching some email and name from another site and iam also getting 
  response but when assining the value to this object `gotomeeting` is not working
and the if statement which checks for the email is  not executing
   `gotomeeting.email = (response from other site)`
can anyone tell me the reason why the response is not assining the value to

```
gotomeeting object property email and name
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using `MutationObserver`? Why would `this.email` not be `null`?

Comment: You need to give more information. How are you calling gotomeeting.getelement() in regards to setting the value of email and name. Do you have to have a value in both variables? You also didn't show any evidence of debugging techniques, you just said it doesn't work, which doesn't explain anything. We need to know the state of whats in ur variables in order to understand what's not working

Comment: I am getting response from  another class method and iam assining to gotomeeting.email property  and name property but email and name is not be assigned to the object

Comment: Please show us the code that is "*fetching some email and name from another site*", as that's probably the culprit. My guess is that your mutation  observer will have found the buttons before the other script has fetched the values, so they won't get set.